# LIKE % or AGAINST for FULLTEXT search?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to make a very fast & efficient approach to fetch the records using keywords as search.

Our MYSQL table **MASTER** tablescontains 30,000 rows and  has 4 fields.

- ID
- title    (**FULLTEXT**)
- short_descr  (**FULLTEXT**)
- long_descr (**FULLTEXT**)

Can any one suggest which is one more efficient?

- **LIKE %**
- MYSQL's **AGAINST**

It would be nice if some one can write a SQL query for the  keywords 
 **Weight Loss Secrets**

```
SELECT id FROM MASTER
WHERE (title LIKE '%Weight Loss Secrets%' OR
       short_descr LIKE '%Weight Loss Secrets%' OR
       long_descr LIKE '%Weight Loss Secrets%')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The full text index should be faster.

Comment: `LIKE OR LIKE OR LIKE` will set your server on fire.

Comment: Both serve different purposes. `AGAINST` returns a number that can be used to sort results by relevancy and the order of words does not matter when matching. `LIKE` performs exact match and there is no relevancy score. Faster is irrelevant.

Comment: One thing for sure, if there are indexes on your row, you won't be able to use them if you start your like with a wild card.

Comment: If you have very big database, don't use MySQL, use Sphinx, Solr, ElasticSearch.

If you want fast search by keywords, then assign them to records, or theme to records. Then you search only one table with all keywords, find keywords you need and their IDs. Use those ids to find records in asoc table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FULLTEXT` index should be faster, maybe its a good idea to add all columns into 1 fulltext index.

```
ALTER TABLE MASTER
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `FullTextSearch` 
(`title` ASC, `short_descr` ASC, `long_descr` ASC);
```

Then execute using `IN BOOLEAN MODE`

```
 SELECT id FROM MASTER WHERE 
 MATCH (title, short_descr, long_descr) 
 AGAINST ('+Weight +Loss +Secrets' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This will find rows that contains all 3 keywords.

**However, this wont give you exact match the keywords just need to be present in same row.**

If you also want exact match you could do like this, but its a bit hacky and would only work if your table doesnt get to big.

```
SELECT id FROM
(
SELECT CONCAT(title,' ',short_descr,' ', long_descr) AS SearchField 
FROM MASTER WHERE 
MATCH (title, short_descr, long_descr) 
AGAINST ('+Weight +Loss +Secrets' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) result WHERE SearchField LIKE '%Weight Loss Secrets%'
```